# How to avoid pointers when using dynamic polymorphism?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

For a long time now I've perceived pointers, `new` and `delete` somewhat unnecessary in C++ unless dealing with long-lived objects, with references being a cleaner alternative that fits better in the RAII model. However, I am still unable to ascertain how to avoid pointers when using dynamic polymorphism in C++.

Supose we have these clasess:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void a() const = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
    virtual void a() const
    {
        std::cout << "B";
    }
};

class C : public A
{
    virtual void a() const
    {
        std::cout << "C";
    }
};

void invoke(const A& obj)
{
    obj.a();
}

int main()
{
    B b;
    invoke(b); // Prints B
}
```

Object can be passed to `invoke` as a reference and there are no pointers involved (well, at least from the programmer's perspective). However, the above example is essentially static polymorphism.

If I wanted to make the type of `b` dependent on something else, I would have to use pointers:

```
int main()
{
    A* a;
    if (something)
        a = new B;
    else
        a = new C;

    invoke(*a); // Prints B
    delete a;
}
```

This looks ugly as hell to me. Sure, I could use smart pointers:

```
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> a;
    if (something)
        a.reset(new B);
    else
        a.reset(new C);
    invoke(*a); // Prints B
}
```

But smart pointers are just wrappers for pointers.

I would like to know if there is a way to avoid this and utilize polymorphic classes without the use of pointers.

Comment: `if(cond) invoke(B(...)) else invoke(C(...))`, aka functional style? Or in C++11 with lambdas if the common parts are big and you don't want an extra global function for it.

Comment: @Xeo It would work in this specific example, but this is not always applicable.

Comment: What you call static polymorphism isn't static polymorphism at all. `invoke` doesn't precisely know the type of its argument. You only **think** it's static polymorphism because you can see the code and the type being passed!

Comment: @Hbcdev I agree. But it behaves exactly as such and may even be optimized by the compiler to not use the virtual function call at all.

Comment: @Tibor: This doesn't work in cases where you need to conditionally store one object or the other, true. In those cases, you won't get around using pointers, since they're essential to dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: @Hbcdev: I think what OP means is to exclude all cases where dynamic binding could be replaced by metaprogramming as all decisions based on the run-time type can be known at compile time. The second the actual type of an object depends on run-time information, you loose some optimisation options. So -- if `something` is a `constexpr`, you *could* call that "static polymorphism" in a manner of speaking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't avoid pointers for this. If you don't like them C++ isn't going to be the language for you, because if you want to do anything polymorphic you're going to have to use pointers to get past the most trivial uses. Constructing objects on the heap, i.e. using `new` is how you avoid the scoped lifetime of stack-constructed objects, which you have to do if you want to make things inside conditional branches and then assign them to variables in a parent scope - if you don't need to do that you also don't actually need polymorphism because your types are all determinable at compile time. There's no way around this.

Use smart pointers of course, they can really help avoid issues with pointer lifecycles, but there'll be pointers in there somewhere no matter what really cool abstractions you end up using.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more sense it makes. If pointers were not required, there would have to be other serious constrains to polymorphic types to avoid slicing, as BЈовић pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

Given your last example, you can avoid the use of pointers (although I don't really see a big problem with smart pointers)

```
struct AHolder {
  std::shared_ptr<A> a;
  operator A const&() const {
    return *a;
  }
  AHolder(bool something)
  : a(something?std::make_shared<B>():std::make_shared<C>()) {
  }
};
```

This lets you use the holder as-if it were the actual object:

```
int main() {
  AHolder a(true); // or whatever argument you like
  invoke(a);
}
```

Comment: Sure, this would work. My question was however, more about avoiding the use of `new` and `*` operator at all.

Comment: @Tibor: Well, the `*` type qualifier as well as the `*` operator are **hidden** inside this facility (which can easily made into a generic template), just as smart pointers hide their use of raw pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why you want to avoid pointers of any kind at all cost. It is absolutely fine to use `std::unique_ptr` / `std::shared_ptr` (when there is a need, of course).
Smart pointers are not "just wrappers" around pointers. They let you to choose between different semantics, and have different uses.

Answer (score 1):

The use case that you're probably thinking about is that of a sort of *factory*, which you can serve perfectly well with a smart pointer and no `new` at all:

```
std::unique_ptr<Message> parse_message(char const * buf, std::size_t len)
{
    if (buf[0] == 'A') { return make_unique<RequestMsg>(buf + 1, len - 1); }

    if (buf[0] == 'R') { return make_unique<AnswerMsg>(buf + 1, len - 1); }

    return nullptr;
}
```

Usage:

```
auto msgptr = parse_msg(buf, len);
```

(You'll need to have a definition of `make_unique` somewhere, which is unfortunately missing from the current standard library but will be amended eventually.)

Comment: The definition of `make_unique` contains a call to `new` though. Fundamentally, you can't get away from pointers to solve this problem, although you can make a variety of pretty and useful abstractions.

Comment: +1 for making me realise that I forgot the `make_` routines (and used dirty ol' `new`).

Comment: @MatthewWalton: Yes, of course. And every single dynamic container in the standard library calls `::new` left right and center. But the point here is to establish a general `new`- and pointer-free idiom for C++! And bear in mind the difference in terms of exception safety that a wrapper function makes.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know if there is a way to avoid this and utilize polymorphic classes without the use of pointers.

No, this is how the c++ was designed in the first place. To avoid slicing, you need to use pointers or references.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way if you need to create objects dynamically and persist them away from function scope. The best you could do here - hide objects creation within factory and smart pointers.

Also you could consider static objects in function scope, but this is not good solution - you could create only limited number of objects this way:

```
template <class T, int Instance> T& create()
{
   static T instance;
   return instance;
}

MyClass& obj1 = create<MyClass, 1>();
MyClass& obj2 = create<MyClass, 2>(); 
MyClass& obj3 = create<MyClass, 3>(); 
// etc
```

This solution has several limitations and rarely could be used. Note that objects are created **statically** at first function call and will persist until the program ends.

Comment: Singletons are generally ugly, and in this case, particularly dangerous. This is effectively a generator for amost-singleton objects.

Comment: @bitmask Of course, and thats because I wrote this is possible, but not good solution. Note that actually you **can** create a lot of objects of same type, so it's not about singletons...

Comment: And *that*'s why I didn't down-vote. Neither did the person who agreed with my previous comment.