# Runtime polymorphism in C++

Tags: runtime, polymorphism

I have an interface, and I was trying an example on dynamic polymorphism as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class foo{
    public:     
        virtual void set();
        virtual void printValue();
};

class fooInt : public foo{
        private:
            int i;
        public:
            int get(){ 
                return i;
            }   
            void set(int val){ //override the set
                i = val;
            }
            void printValue(){
                cout << i << endl;
            }           
};

int main(){
    foo *dt;         //Create a base class pointer
    dt = new fooInt; //Assign a sub class reference
    dt->set(9);
}
```

However when I compile this, I get no matching function for call to ‘foo::set(int)’. Where am I going wrong? I tried to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213328/how-to-avoid-pointers-when-using-dynamic-polymorphism) article, and I still couldn't figure out the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class foo` has no method `set(int)`. It has a method `set()`, but no method `set(int)`.

If you intend to override an inherited method, the superclass method and your method must have the same signature:

```
class foo {
  ...
  // If you really want an abstract class, the `= 0`
  //  ensures no instances can be created (makes it "pure virtual")
  virtual void set(int) = 0;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, ok. So if I want to inherit this abstract class and use a string instead of int, then will I have to overload `virtual void set(int) = 0;` in class foo?

Comment: @rgamber No; if you want to use a string instead, `foo` will need methods taking `string`. **In order to override a method, the signature (parameter count and types) of the superclass method and the signature of your method must match.** You can't override `void foo(int)` with `void foo(string)`.

Comment: I meant overload in the abstract class i.e. the abstract class will then contain 2 get methods, one for each type.

Comment: Oh. \*facepalm\* Misread your first comment. Yes, that would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your definition of

```
    virtual void set();
```

Should be

```
    virtual void set(int val);
```

Comment: Nitpick: That's not a definition, that's just a declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The corrected program is given here

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class foo {

public:
    virtual  void set(int val)=0;////////here you have void set() function with no argument but you tried to override void set(int val) which take one argument.
    virtual void printValue()=0;
};

class fooInt : public foo{
private:
    int i;
public:

    fooInt()
    {
        cout<<"constructor called\n";
    }
    int get(){
        return i;
    }
    void set(int val){ //override the set


        i = val;
    }
    void printValue(){
        cout << i << endl;
    }
};

int main(){


    foo *dt;       //Create a base class pointer
    dt=new fooInt;
    dt->set(9);
    dt->printValue();
}
```

Fault of the previous program were

1.You tried to override set() {no argument} with set(int val){one argument}.
2.When a class contain a pure virtual function,it must be implemented by its derived classes.
3. No object can be created of a class which contain a pure virtual function.But ref can be created.
Thanks